# Div Elements Overlapping In Responsive

Tags: html, css, image, blogs

I am a novice when it comes to HTML and CSS and have been stuck working on this for months. I would like to have a div element that contains a table on the top left of the page. Next to it, I would like and an image and then text below that image that then wraps around the table on the left.

I was able to accomplish this and thought all was good, but then I discovered that when viewed in mobile, the images and text overlap the div with the table and I cannot figure out how to correct it. You can see a sample of what I am talking about at

https://www.reviewsfromthecouch.com/2019/11/dr-phibes-rises-again-film-review/

Here is all the code I have been working with on this problem.

```css
.wrapper {
  float: left;
  clear: right;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
}

.col-md-6 {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}

.col-md-3 {
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <table style="height: 508px; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #d90e00; border-style: solid;">
    <tbody>
      <tr style="height: 225px;">
        <td style="background-color: #d90e00; height: 225px; width: 100%; border-top: none; border-bottom: none;"><img class="size-full wp-image-3281 aligncenter" src=”[IMAGE]” alt="[IMAGE-TITLE]" width="150" height="225" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 24px;">
        <td style="background-color: #d90e00; height: 24px; width: 100%; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; border-top: none; border-bottom: none;"><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; display: block;"> TEXT </span></strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 24px;">
        <td style="height: 24px; width: 100%; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; border-top: none; border-bottom: none;"><span style="font-size: 10pt;"> TEXT </span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 24px;">
        <td style="background-color: #d90e00; height: 24px; width: 100%; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; border-top: none; border-bottom: none;"><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; display: block;"> TEXT </span></strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 24px;">
        <td style="height: 24px; width: 100%; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; border-top: none; border-bottom: none;"><span style="font-size: 10pt;"> TEXT </span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 24px;">
        <td style="background-color: #d90e00; height: 24px; width: 100%; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; border-top: none; border-bottom: none;"><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; display: block;"> TEXT </span></strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 24px;">
        <td style="height: 24px; width: 100%; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; border-top: none; border-bottom: none;"><span style="font-size: 10pt;"> TEXT </span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 19px;">
        <td style="background-color: #d90e00; height: 24px; width: 100%; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; border-top: none; border-bottom: none;"><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; display: block;"> TEXT </span></strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 24px;">
        <td style="width: 100%; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; border-top: none; border-bottom: none; height: 24px;"><span style="font-size: 10pt;"> TEXT </span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 24px;">
        <td style="background-color: #d90e00; height: 24px; width: 100%; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; border-top: none; border-bottom: none;"><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; display: block;"> TEXT </span></strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 24px;">
        <td style="height: 24px; width: 100%; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; border-top: none; border-bottom: none;"><span style="font-size: 10pt;"> TEXT </span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 24px;">
        <td style="background-color: #d90e00; height: 24px; width: 100%; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; border-top: none; border-bottom: none;"><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; display: block;"> TEXT </span></strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 24px;">
        <td style="height: 24px; width: 100%; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; border-top: none; border-bottom: none;"><span style="font-size: 10pt;"> TEXT </span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <h4><img class="img-responsive wp-image-3279" src=”[IMAGE]” alt="[IMAGE-TITLE]" width="100%" height="470" />
    <img class="alignnone wp-image-1912" src=”[IMAGE]” alt="[IMAGE-TITLE]" width="100" height="56" />
    <br><strong><i> TEXT </i></strong><br></h4>
</div>
TEXT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have styled your css for all the elements according to  `%` percentages, each and every element will acquire that much amount of screen in `%` percentage even when the width changes to overcome this you must use **Media Queries** by which you can style the elements according to the changing sizes of screens and the website becomes responsive.

For more details about Media Queries [Click Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: Thank you. I will have to read up on this and see how to apply it.

Comment: Yes i you find my answer helpful please can you accept it.